# SQL Restore backup file error

Tags: mysql

```
mysql -u root -paaum corpdb <  /home/aaum/Videos/sp_getNOnAirDetails1.sql
```

ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

**i think so there is some problem with my sql file**

Comment: Can we actually see your sql file, though ? Its 4th line could be of help, just saying...

Comment: We are not **clairvoyant**. But if you show us the top few lines of `sp_getNOnAirDetails1.sql` maybe we could be of some assistance

Comment: DECLARE SERVICETYPE INT

Comment: NO. Show us at least to the line with the error, and ADD IT TO YOUR QUESTION

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally bugged the problem. i forget to assign delimeter .

Answer (score 0):

Try the commands as shown below :

Login into your mysql console and run :

mysql> use corpdb;

mysql> source /home/aaum/Videos/sp_getNOnAirDetails1.sql;

If your dump file is executed perfectly then the issue is not with the file.

It's about how you are trying to import the file.

The command which you have provided is absolutely fine. But I see that probably you might be executing the command from  MySQL console.

mysql> mysql -u root -paaum corpdb <  /home/aaum/Videos/sp_getNOnAirDetails1.sql
Not a right way to import, try to import the file from terminal.

If you still see any errors then please post them here.